# MFMailComposeViewController appears for a second then disappears

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have done the usual set up of the MFMailComposeViewController() as per Swift Guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/

but when I run this then the email appears for a split second, disappears and I get the error message "MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly".

here is the full code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func showEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["address@example.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("Hello!")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("Hello from California!", isHTML: false)

    // Present the view controller modally.
    self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
    didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    default:
        break
    }
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in the xcode simulator. It should work fine on your device.

Comment: thank you for this answer - I thought I'll turn crazy - since I followed the exact instructions on Apple Developer Site.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The `MFMailComposeViewController` component can't be tested in the `iOS simulator` only in the `device`.

If you look this [Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4415) in `Apple Developer Forums` the problem has a ticket in `Apple Bug Report` but still without any fix.